# Install i3-gaps 18.04

Tags: compiling, i3-wm

I'm trying to install i3-gaps on Ubuntu 18.04, but I keep getting an error when I hit `sudo make install`; I also installed `libxcb-shape0-dev` dependency.

The error I'm getting is : https://pastebin.com/Ek09j4ta ( I don't know how to arrange to get the whole code in a box maybe someone can help with this)

I also know how to install these dotfiles users provide (I only check /r/unixporn) .

Comment: I would suggest opening an issue on github since they seem to be very active, and very few are familiar with it here. You have more chances of getting an answer there.

Comment: So this might be an Ubuntu problem. But just asking now does it matter if it's Gnome or KDE beacuse I want to ditch Windows but I also want to switch to i3 (if it's possible) and I really enjoy Kubuntu and i'm asking if it's possible to have i3 even with Kubuntu installed

Comment: I don't know anything about i3-gaps so it might be answered here but it's also better to copy paste it on github issue tracker just to increase your chances to get answers by posting it here and there https://github.com/Airblader/i3/issues

Comment: Make sure You have installed everything listed here : https://github.com/Airblader/i3/wiki/Building-from-source